# Invalid Cast when dealing with @@Identity

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I have a winforms app that includes the following class method:

```
public aSqlQuery(SqlCommand pSqlCom, string pMode = "object", bool pGetID = false)
    {
        try
        {
            string strConnection = aSystem.ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection linkToDB = new SqlConnection(strConnection);
            pSqlCom.Connection = linkToDB;

            switch (pMode)
            {
                case "non query":
                    {
                        linkToDB.Open();
                        pSqlCom.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        if (pGetID == true)
                        {
                            SqlCommand sqlCom = new SqlCommand("SELECT @@IDENTITY;", linkToDB);
                            this.LastID = (int)sqlCom.ExecuteScalar();
                        }
                        linkToDB.Close();
                    }
                    break;
```

plus other switches

The pSqlCom (SqlCommand) executes fine becuase I can see the data written into the database.  However the subsequent "SELECT @@IDENTITY" statement gives an invalid cast error
What am I doing wrong and how can I retrieve the new ID created by SQL within my class method?

Comment: What does "sqlCom.ExecuteScalar();" actually returns to you?

Comment: This is great resource, read the full thread please, same to @Martin Smith http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1174930/int32-tryparse-or-intcommand-executescalar/1175048#1175048

Comment: @Yaroslav - Not sure why you are telling me to read it. The answer there in no way negates the comment I made on your answer.

Comment: I am probably doing a stupid question, but are you sure that the table on which you perform the INSERT contains an IDENTITY column? I have code like yours and never seen this problem.

Comment: @Steve that would explain why `@@IDENTITY` is returning null and failing the cast.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The correct answer it turns out was that the SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() statement had to form part of the same SqlCommand as the INSERT statement which preceeded it, but which I had contained in the previous SqlCommand 'pSqlCom'.  Once the SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() was incuded as part of pSqlCom the code correctly returned the Identity.

Answer (score 1):

Insert the row and get the Id it is was given with [`SCOPE_IDENTIY()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx), don't use `@@IDENTITY`.

You need to use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` on the same connection and scope, just after the `INSERT`.

---

<s>In your example no `INSERT` is performed on your connection so you can't expect to get the last generated Id.</s>

In your example its not clear that `pSqlCom` performs an `INSERT`, if it does not any indentity function will return `NULL` which cannot be converted to `int`

---

**EDIT**

You want to use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` and you want to do it in the same `Command` as the `INSERT`.

So, your statement should be somthing like

```
var sql =
@"INSERT <Your Data> <Your Table>;
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTIY();"

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(strConnection))
{
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
    {
        connection.Open();
        object result = command.ExecuteScalar();
    }
}

int? id = (int?)(!Convert.IsDBNull(result) ? result : null);
```

Comment: Scope_Identity() gives the same error message.  Please clarify scope.  I thought that if the pSqlCom AND "SELECT SCOPE_IDENTIY();" where executed back to back on the same connection, that that would qulify as the 'same scope'.  Am I wrong in assuming this?

Comment: Its a Sql Insert Command that puts a new entry into a database table - which works - because each ettempt succesfully inserts the data into the database, but I am unable to retrieve the ID created by SQL server.

Comment: @PJW You wan't to use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` as a second statement in the same `Command`.

Comment: @PJW concerning the specific cast problem, I suspect that `@@IDENTITY` is returning null, which cannot be cast to `int`

Comment: @@Idnetity shoudl never be used to return the identity just inserted, it will give the worng answer if someone ever puts a trigger onteh table that inserts to another table with an indetity. Worse, you will not find this out until your data is setroyed beyond your abilty to fix. SO even if you have no triggers now, it s an exptremely dangerous practice to use @@identity.

Answer (score -2):

Your call to the command should be returning something not of scalar type. Indeed you need to use Int32 instead. Chek [ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx) on MSDN.

Also, I recommend you to use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` instead of `@@Identity`. Check the [following link](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/) for a detailed explanation.

Comment: If the ID is an integer how can it not be a scalar?  Also I started by using SCOPE_INDENTITY() and got the same error message so I reverted to @@IDENTITY as a second option - but I got no further.

Comment: Think before giving a minus one. I could do the same with your question as it denotes lack of research. But I prefer instead to answer and help. Check my answer again

Comment: `(Int32) cmd.ExecuteScalar();` and `(int) cmd.ExecuteScalar();` are synonymous.

Comment: The link I posted clearly states that on ExecuteScalar INT cannot be used. I'm not stating that are synonimous or not, just answering the question, using INT will fail, as can be read on both the link on this site, on MSDN and many posts on other forums by doing  a quick search. @AVD has already clearly pointed out where the problem resides

Comment: @Yaroslav - Your answer suggests that the OP needs to "use Int32 instead" I just pointed out that this will make zero difference. `int` is just a `C#` keyword for the same thing.

Comment: @MartinSmith more on the subject http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7803375/casting-exception-when-trying-to-get-value-from-executescalar  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8736337/trying-to-pass-recent-id-with-scope-identity-and-its-error-me-specified-cast And there is even more

Comment: @Yaroslav the links don't really support your case as far as I can tell.

Comment: Ok...kill me...but the answer given by @adrift on the 2nd link is not far from what I'm answering. I did not said on any moment that INT or INT32 are different or alike, just recommended to use INT32 cast. Is not exactly the answer, but is not definitely totally wrong to the point of receiving two minus one....whatever...

Comment: The good thing of this answer is that even the OP accepted his own answer and acknowledged that using `SCOPE_IDENTITY` solves his problem.